# Как изменить цвет текста в Status Bar?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Почему-то перестал меняться цвет текста в Status Bar. Я это проверил в только что созданном проекте - не работает. Хотя до этого эта строка не подводила:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Чем это может быть вызвано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы так менять цвет необходимо в `Info.plist` указать

`View controller-based status bar appearance`  `NO`

Raw (Open As -> Source Code):

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```